# Howto Store 2 combined unique key in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value, unique-key

I want to store values that are binded to a name + number.
Like, (John,1) (RED) and (John,2) (BLUE) and (Elize,1) (GREEN)
So how can i store a 2 keys that are combineded unique?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new type which represents the composite key (the name and the number here). You'll need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`, and I'd strongly advise you to make the type immutable. For example:

```
public final class NameIntPair {
    private final int intValue;
    private final String name;

    public NameIntPair(int intValue, String name) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + intValue;
        hash = hash * 31 + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof NameIntPair)) {
           return false;
        }
        if (this == obj) {
           return true;
        }
        NameIntPair other = (NameIntPair) obj;
        return other.intValue == intValue && Objects.equal(other.name, name);
    }
}
```

I'm using `Objects.equal` from Guava for convenience to avoid explicit nullity checks here - if you're not using Guava, you'd either have to use an equivalent or handle nullity in the code. Alternatively, you may well want to prevent null names, validating this in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but i never worked with hashcode/equals in a HashMap, could u make an example how i can get the value of John,1 ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use a String concatenation if I'm sure about the uniqueness of the combination and if the keys object are easy to stringify. I might use a special character to join the keys (like "John#1" and "John#2").

If I'm not sure about that I'll use [Guava's Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html):

> Typically, when you are trying to index on more than one key at a
>   time, you will wind up with something like Map(FirstName,
>   Map(LastName, Person)), which is ugly and awkward to use. Guava
>   provides a new collection type, Table, which supports this use case
>   for any "row" type and "column" type

So a Table is

> A collection that associates an ordered pair of keys, called a row key
>   and a column key, with a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Define your specific Key class like this :

```
public class Key {
    final String name;
    final int number;
    public Key(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result
                + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + number;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Key other = (Key) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (number != other.number)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    private Test getOuterType() {
        return Test.this;
    }
 }
```

The important point is to ensure that you respect the contract of equals and hashCode to enable your collection (any standard collection using key) to work as intended.

Here I simply used the generated methods produced by Eclipse but there are also many dynamic utilities (for example in Guava) helping you on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is also simple alternative approach with concatenated key suitable for this case:

```
public static String getKey(String name, int number) {
    return name + number;
}
```

If names are not too long, overhead for string concatenation won't be greater than for creating composite key objects suggested in other answers.